# Regex Pattern for String at least 4 characters containing a specific character at the end of String

Tags: java, regex, string

I am attempting to create a regex patter for the following case:

> The String must contain the character '%' once and only once as the last character of the String. The String must be at least 4 characters including the '%'. The String can only be a max of 35 chars(including the %)

I currently have this pattern: `[^~,]{3,}[$%]` which covers all cases except for duplicate `%` characters.

How can you explicitly say in my regex: "Occur once and only once as the last character in the String"

Some examples with `.matches(<regex_pattern>) results`

- `ABC%` -> TRUE
- `AB%` -> FALSE
- `ABCDEFGHIJKLMN%` -> TRUE
- `AB%C%` -> FALSE
- `%ABC%` -> FALSE
- `@!#$%` -> TRUE
- `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZABCDEFGHIJ%` -> FALSE (36 chars + the percent = 36)

Comment: `[^%]{3,34}%$`?

Comment: How about just specifying that the first 3-34 characters not be a %? You're already specifying that they not be a tilde or comma.

Comment: Andy exactly what I was looking for, did not think about doing basically the exact opposite of what I was looking at. Submit as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you simply need:

```
^[^%]{3,34}%$
```

Which means:

- The start of the string
- Followed by between 3 and 34 characters which aren't `%`
- Followed by `%`
- Followed by the end of the string

(Depending upon how you use this regex, explicit start and end anchors `^` and `$` may not be necessary)

I think it's worth pointing out that regex isn't necessary, and doing it without can yield a more readable condition:

```
boolean matches =
       str.length() >= 4
    && str.length() <= 35
    && str.endsWith("%")
    && str.indexOf("%") == str.length() - 1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to allow spaces, for example `ABCD %`

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper spaces are allowed already. Do you mean that you do not want spaces to be counted as part of the 4-35 characters?

Comment: No, I meant spaces were allowed. My regex calculator wasn't allowing them. I refreshed and now it is. But to clarify for my understanding, the space character is allowed under the "All characters except `%`" in this example.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper yes, exactly.